# WebSphere MQ check string with mq message

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, mq

I want to read the first MQ message off a queue (without removing it) and save this message into my database. Then if everything is done I need to permanently remove this message off the MQ queue. What I do know, is to just delete the first message in the queue. But how do I know if the same message that I saved into the database is the same one I will delete from the MQ?

Thanks,
Michael

**Edit:**
Now tried to handle the actions with a TransactionScope in C#(Console Application):

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope){
    //MQ Connection ( read message of queue)
    Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
    properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, _settings.MQServer);
    properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, _settings.MQPort);
    properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, _settings.MQChannelName);
    properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT);
    MQQueueManager _MQHandler = new MQQueueManager(_settings.MQManager, properties);

    MQQueue = _MQHandler.AccessQueue(ReceiveQueueName,
    MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
    MQQueueMessage = new MQMessage();
    MQQueueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
    MQQueueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
    MQQueueGetMessageOptions.Options += MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;     //new
    MQQueue.Get(MQQueueMessage, MQQueueGetMessageOptions);

    //DB Connection (save message in database)

    if ( DBsuccess ) {
        _MQHandler.Commit();
        scope.Complete();   
    }else{
        _MQHandler.Backout();
    }           

}
```

This seems to do what I want :) But some question:
- If I make a syncpoint at a Put/Get, then call the Backout(), will the MQ only rollback to this syncpoint?
- Is the MQ blocked for other MQ managers, if a message is a unit of work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a transactional get from Websphere MQ in dotnet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084849/how-to-do-a-transactional-get-from-websphere-mq-in-dotnet)

Comment: You should consider using XA transaction for that instead of doing it manually.

Comment: So in my understanding.. the answer of the duplicate question lock the queue so that just one access is allowed or?

Comment: @Gas do you have an example of a XA transaction with mq?

Comment: Check this page for start [WebSphere MQ Distributed transactions in .NET](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/un11380_.htm)

Comment: How do I know if the Extended Transaction Client is already installed in the WebSphere MQ? If it already is set up, is the SimpleXAGet the right way to handle a transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to clarify some terminology, the message is on the queue, not the channel - the channel just gives you access into a queue manager. So in effect you want to 'get' the first message (inside a unit of work  with GMO_SYNCPOINT), store it into a database, and if the storing works, remove the message from a queue (via a commit). To do this, you would get the message from the queue in a unit of work, and only 'commit' the get (ie make it happen) and the database update at the same time. Generally speaking, you would use transaction coordination, to ensure the database update and the get either both happen (commit) or neither happen (rollback). Hopefully you can use the o/s DTC (distributed transaction coordinator) to make both MQ and the database participate in the same transaction - you also need to look at whether you want managed or unmanaged connections as they are different implementations - See the info center http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029290_.htm

Comment: I looked into the links above and now have a better view of how to handle this, thanks! I connect the queue with a C# console application..so its an unmanaged code, right? Do you have an example of a transaction in C#?

Comment: MQ .net library can make connections and flow data direct to MQ systems staying fully within the .net environment (managed) or it can make the MQI calls through the normal C client (unmanaged, the default). Historically unmanaged was fully functional and unmanaged was less so, although over time they are much closer. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029290_.htm and its child pages talks about how it all works

Comment: Hiya, You are getting with browse (leaving the message there), then saving the message you got, then destructively getting the message on the front of the queue. This is both VERY dangerous (if you run 2 copies of the app to scale it, they both save the first message, and throw away 2) and extra calls....  Look at MQGMO_SYNCPOINT. Make the first get a GET with gmo_syncpoint, and then save in the database under the unit of work. Then you commit or rollback. If you commit, the 'get' destroys the message, if you rollback then the 'get' is undone and the message is put back on the queue.